# Global macros for KaTeX in docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus, katex

I'm trying out docusaurus to write a rather technical manual.
One of the requirements is LaTeX support with macros.
Macros allow me to make fewer mistakes and easily change how some output looks for the entire document at once.
E.g. in stead of writing `\text{P}_\text{location} = 5 \text{mbar}` I could write `\def\plocation#1{<definition>}` and then `\plocation{5}`.

Docusaurus supports KaTeX, which in turn supports global macros. At least, in theory. I can't get it to work, unfortunately.

I've tried setting `globalGroup: true` in the config. I've also tried adding macros to the config itself. Stripped version of my config below.

Just to check defining macros does work, `\def\x#1{x+#1}\x{5}` results in `x+5`.
Adding `\global` or replacing `\def` with `\gdef` does not work.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this just not supported?

```
...

const macros = {
  "\\x": "x+1"
};

/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
const config = {
    ...  
    presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          ...
          remarkPlugins: [math],
          rehypePlugins: [katex, {
            throwOnError: true,
            globalGroup: true,
            macros
          }],
        },
        ...
      }),
    ],
  ],
 ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As one should, I figured out what I did wrong 34 minutes after posting this.

When adding config to a plugin, the plugin and config need to be inside `[...]`.

The proper config is:

```
rehypePlugins: [[katex, {
    throwOnError: true,
    globalGroup: true,
    macros
}]],
```